Is there any possibility to rebuild a broken Graylog Opensearch instance?
Good morning!
I'm having problems with a broken Graylog OpenSearch instance. The corruption of the data must have happened, when I upgraded to a wrong version of OpenSearch (a newer version of OpenSearch than is supported by this version of Graylog).
Is there any possibility to "rebuild" the Graylog OpenSearch indices and start from scratch without deleting/reinstalling Graylog (and MongoDB) itself?
Thanks in advance!

Problem solved in the meantime. Managed to reinstall OpenSearch and Graylog. MongoDB left untouched. Works like a charm, again.
